# Shesha nag is Laxman and Balaram. Why isn't he part of earlier Vishnu avatars?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

Of the known 9 Vishnu avatars, Shesha nag part of only 2 avatars as Laxman and balaram.
Why isn't he mentioned in other avatars like Narasimha, Vaman